# htaccess redirect user-friendly url to get variable 'url' and query string to be tacked on the end

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have an htaccess file that currently directs the entire url minus any query string to a query string variable url....

`RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]`

*page/subpage/important/thingy/?t=10*

becomes

*index.php?url=page/subpage/important/thingy/*

the query string was ignored by design originally. now we need it added but in such a way that...

*page/subpage/important/thingy/?t=10&name=Bob&food=cheese*

should become...

*index.php?**url=**page/subpage/important/thingy/**&t=**10**&name=**Bob**&food=**cheese*

in short, the user-friendly component is assigned to a get variable url and the rest are tacked on.

Can anyone tell me where to begin with this or how to modify the rewrite rule to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to use `QSA` flag to append query string.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Justin. I modified the htaccess file accordingly, I entered /home/?hello=dolly&me=hungry and the part sent to the $_GET['url'] was /home/. Is there a conflict in the reg ex?

Comment: This is a normal behaviour since you get other params with `$_GET['food']` and `$_GET['name']` following your question's example. If you want it to be part of url param, you must encode `&`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought it would be added to the end of the string passed to $_GET['url']. Sorry, yesterday was a long day! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa @Justin Iurman's answer should have solved it, i.e. the QSA flag.

I finally managed to get this working using the following:

`RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-/]+)?$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]`